# How to make healthbar decrease in unity

Tags: c#, unity

I want to build a health bar which show's the energy of the player.I have two buttons "PLAY" and "IDLE" to show the animation.when I click on the "PLAY" button the character start running along with that the health bar should decreases it's energy.Here is the code written for the two button clicks

```
void OnGUI()
{
            if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 200, 50, 50), "PlAY")) {
                    animation.Play ("run");
            }
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 500, 50, 50), "IDLE")) {
        animation.Play ("idle");
    }
    }
```

Now I need to create a health bar to show the decreasing of energy when the player starts its animation.Could you please help me in coding out creating energy bar.

[image]

Done the code for creating the progress bar,but the bar is not getting decremented.Here is the code

```
private float loadBarProgress = 0.0f;
private const float loadBarSpeed = 0.25f;
public Texture loadBarTexture = null;
void OnGUI()
{
    //Draw loading bar with offset texture coordinates
    GUI.DrawTextureWithTexCoords(new Rect(Screen.width * 0.4f, Screen.height * 0.4f, Screen.width * 0.2f, Screen.height * 0.1f), loadBarTexture, new Rect(loadBarProgress, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), false);
}
// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    //Move the bar along; keep it's position between zero and one for best float point precision
    loadBarProgress += Time.deltaTime * loadBarSpeed;
    if (loadBarProgress >= 1.0f) loadBarProgress -= 1.0f;
}
```

Comment: You should show what you've already tried.

Comment: Also, a quick search shows plenty of tutorials in-case you didn't try anything yet.

Comment: I have done search and tried out the sample.

Comment: @bummzack yes its duplicate of the above question.Here I have specified only one issue

Comment: Wait for Unity 4.6. The new GUI system will make this very simple.

Answer (score 1):

To normalize a value divide it by the maximum amount allowed.
So if your character can have a maximum energy amount of 100 and has a current energy level of 30.... 30/100=0.3

Same works for any numbers Max energy 340 current energy of 50.... 50/340 = 0.147
Be aware if your doing this math in c# on integers you'll need to cast them to float before the operation like this,

```
scale = (float)currentEnergy / (float)maxEnergy;
```

if current and max are already floats you can skip the casting into floats

So your `Rect` should be made using this multiplier.

```
GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 40, 100 * scale, 20), "Energy");
```

So simply update your `currentEnergy` variable somewhere in your code and the bar will scale accordingly.

Comment: A simple solution and great first post.

Comment: Also make sure to draw a full scale bar behind the scaled one (to give a reference).